# Ubuntu recognizes only USB as partition during installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

[image: screenshots]

My main issue is picture 1 (left-upper). During installation, Ubuntu recognizes only the USB as a partition.

Background:
My goal is to install Ubuntu on this computer. No Dual-boot, No Windows. The computer has an SSD and HDD. I want to format both and install Ubuntu on the SSD

I bought the computer yesterday, so I am not too familiar with the hardware background.

One thing I did notice that I can both choose Boot priority (right upper) and boot device priority (left lower). What are the best settings to chose in those menu's. For this issue, I set the USB as the primary devide in both menu's.

The guy who sold me the computer, installed a clean Windows 8.1 for me. That allowed me to open Disk Manager via Windows (right lower) and see what's happening. Unfortunately, it's in Dutch. But the black spaces are unallocated space and the blue spaces are the real disks. Note, I made the unallocated space myself, hoping it would solve the issue.

Question:
What steps can I take to install Ubuntu? I want to install ubuntu as the first and only OS.

Solution:
I changed the SATA cable for the SSD from SATA4 to SATA1 port on the motherboard

Comment: The line on the Install screen that says "Kingston Data Traveler" is actually a drop-down menu. Can you select the SSH from it? From there it should be pretty straightforward - select the entire disk, format it, and install Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Jos, thank you for your help.
The drop-down menu only shows my "Kingston Data Traveler". I think the Ubuntu thinks the only available media are the USB stick, how can I give it access to the SSD and HDD?

Comment: I found out my computer has no UEFI. Hope that might help

Comment: Sorry, I'm at a loss here...of course the Ubuntu installer should identify all disks recognized by the BIOS, and offer to install Ubuntu on them. I would suggest you reboot from the LiveUSB and opt for "Try Ubuntu". Then we can run some diagnostics on it, which you can't do from the installer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not put `SOLVED` in the title, just check the check-mark onto the answer which was most helpful for you. Or put your own findings as an answer. this way this question can be marked as answered.Thank you.

Comment: Found the solution Jos. On another forum I found a suggestion to change the SATA cables. My motherboard allows for 6gb/s SATA ports. However, when I put them back to the "normal" ports, it all worked